Storing ORM metadata, results and queries to predis cache
We have a symfony 2.8 app running (yes, it's old, we are in the process of upgrading).
I'm trying to set up our caching for the ORM to use our Redis instances, but I keep getting and Address not available [tcp://localhost:6379] error.
This is my config:
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                metadata_cache_driver: predis
                result_cache_driver: predis
                query_cache_driver: predis

snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn:
                - redis://redis?alias=master
                - redis://redis
            options:
                replication: true

    doctrine:
        metadata_cache:
            client: default
            entity_manager: default
        result_cache:
            client: default
            entity_manager: default
        query_cache:
            client: default
            entity_manager: default

The DSN refers to the docker container running that is named redis. snc_redis is configured correctly, because other items being stored in the cache is showing up and being updated.
Why would the abstract connection be trying to connect to localhost? If I have just snc_redis and not the doctrine.orm configuration, it still doesn't store to cache.
